Simple .txt file cannot be read into R from URL anymore
I teach a quantitative methods course in R where I access data from an online repository. Last year the link worked fine using read.delim(). This year, of course, I'm getting an error that I cannot make sense of. The error says "cannot open a connection to [the URL]" and a follow-up error says "HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'".
There's no fancy API on this repository and the link itself works fine outside of R. Anyone know how to get around this and why it might have changed over a year? Really makes teaching easy, this stuff...
Website with data:
https://datadryad.org/stash/dataset/doi:10.5061/dryad.5bg1dt3
(click on the date on the right-hand ribbon to show the data files- I know, poor design)
Line that no longer works:
d  <- read.delim('https://datadryad.org/stash/downloads/file_stream/55707')
So simple... why?!?

There actualy is Dryad API and they probably want you to use it for any automated access - https://datadryad.org/stash/api (linked in Help menu)
It's still the same file id as in the link from the page, just slightly different request:
d <- read.delim("https://datadryad.org/api/v2/files/55707/download")
tibble::as_tibble(d)
#> # A tibble: 44 × 4
#>    Stem.ID Diameter Wet.mass Dry.mass
#>      <int>    <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1       1        1      0.8      0.3
#>  2       2        1      0.6      0.3
#>  3       3        1      0.2      0.1
#>  4       4        1      0.2      0.2
#>  5       5        1      0.4      0.1
#>  6       6        1      0.3      0.2
#>  7       7        1      0.3      0.1
#>  8       8        1      0.3      0.1
#>  9       9        2      0.7      0.6
#> 10      10        2      1.1      0.9
#> # ℹ 34 more rows

Created on 2024-08-30 with reprex v2.1.1

margusl- how did you get around the API in this example? I don't see it in the code you posted.

I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you mean, it's a complete example and just follows https://datadryad.org/stash/api#/files/get_files__id__download  with the file id from your question (55707), basic API calls do not require account nor authentication.
If you need to browse though dataset versions and list all available files, you'd need to go though few more calls and some parsing.

My bad- I didn't see the different URL you used before asking that question. Thanks for your help- greatly appreciated!
